# Одинаковые IP  при VLSM. Что будет?

Tags: ip, маршрутизация

Что будет если к маршрутизатору верхнего уровня (192.168.128.0/25) подключить и компьютер с 192.168.128.15 и маршрутизатор нижнего уровня (192.168.128.0/26), к которому подключен компьютер с таким же IP?В общем случае, что будет если в сети есть два хоста с одинаковыми ИП, но они расположены в сетях с масками разных длин? Вот примерчик в виде схемки:![схема][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA5RC.png

Comment: Я не совсем понял, в чем заключается проблема? IP будут не одинаковые, т.к. у них разные маски подсети. Никаких противоречий нет.

Comment: @DUP, можете схемку набросать?

Comment: Примерно набросал.

Answer (score 1):

IP будут не одинаковые, т.к. у них разные маски подсети. Никаких противоречий нет.

Comment: А если "снаружи" послать на этот IP пинг. Он прийдет куда? - Где длиннее маска? Тогда, как послать пинг на на другой хост с этим же IP.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от таблиц маршрутизации. Куда пакет пошлют они - туда и пойдут.